# is there a way to dynamicaly add a widget on top of another widget

Tags: android, android-layout

i'm trying to create a widget called DecoView dynamicaly every time i press a button.

if i just put two deco views in the XML i can see them both and they both look fine on ontop of the other.

but when i try to add it dynamicly in the code, i only create the first one, 
and all the rest just aren't get created

what am i missing here ?
can someone help me with this ?

my mainActivity.java

```
package com.example.shay_v.dynamicdecoviewexample;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.PointF;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.hookedonplay.decoviewlib.DecoView;
import com.hookedonplay.decoviewlib.charts.SeriesItem;
import com.hookedonplay.decoviewlib.events.DecoEvent;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    Button mainMenuButton;
    int widgetInteger = 1;
    LinearLayout ll;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //pointing to display
        mainMenuButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        mainMenuButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        //points to the linear layout in the xml
        ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainMenu_mainLayout);

    }

    private void createDecoViewWidget (int i) {

        //adds params to the linear layout
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        //deco view widget
        DecoView decoViewWidget = new DecoView(this);

        //adding to view
        decoViewWidget.setId(i);
        ll.addView(decoViewWidget, params);


        //decoViewWidget.configureAngles((int) (Math.random() * 360) + 1, (int) (Math.random() * 100));

        //Create data series track
        SeriesItem seriesItem = new SeriesItem.Builder(Color.argb(255, (int) (Math.random()*255), (int) (Math.random()*255), (int) (Math.random()*255)))
            //third controller is end point

            .setRange(0, 100, 0)
            .setLineWidth(60f)
            .setInset(new PointF(120f, 120f))
            .build();

        int series1Index = decoViewWidget.addSeries(seriesItem);

        decoViewWidget.addEvent(new DecoEvent.Builder((float) (Math.random() * 100)).setIndex(series1Index).setDelay(1000).build());


    }

    //button listener
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        createDecoViewWidget (widgetInteger);
        widgetInteger++;

    }
}
```

my activity_main.xml >

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.shay_v.dynamicdecoviewexample.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:id="@+id/mainMenu_mainLayout"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"></LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

anyone ?

Answer (score 0):

When you are creating the Views they are being added into a `LinearLayout`. This type of layout will position the views one after the other, so the second view is being drawn off the visible area of the screen.

As you want all views to be drawn on top of each other you should use a `RelativeLayout`.